# "boss of whose" or "boss of whom"

Tags: grammar, relative-pronouns, possessives

Person 1: You look like a boss!

Person 2: Becase I'm a boss.

Person 3: Boss of whose?

I want to know if person 3 is using "whose" right or if "whom" is needed to make the sentence grammatical.

Note.
I know that I can say "whose boss?"
And I be correct. But I would like to know if is even possible to have a question constructed like that and if it will be correct grammatically speaking.

All answers will be appreciated. Thanks...

Comment: Do you have some examples (or can you search online for some) that use "of whose"?

Comment: No I don't have and I can't find any online that is why I'm asking if is even possible to make such construction.

Comment: *Whose boss....* suits better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**of** requires a noun or pronoun in the accusative form, for example

> here is a photo of **me** - me is the accusative of I.

**Whose** is the genitive form of **who**, so you can't use it after **of**. You have to used the accusative form, which is **whom**.

> Boss of whom?

This is the definitely the best way to say it in this context, because it places the emphasis on **Boss**. You could also say "Whose boss?" but this is less effective because it places emphasis on **whose**.